# Swift 3: How to animate a view background color similar to a progress bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, progress-bar

When the user enters the view controller which contains the image below, i would like the blue color to be animated based on the value which in this case is 70. This means, the color starts loading up from 0px in the view and stops at the amount of whatever the value is. Also, i would like the number to be counting from 0 to the end value at the same time the color is loading. Are there any tips/ links or some direction you could point me into in order to achieve this? Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `progressView` with the desired `backgroundColor`

```
let progressView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 50))
progressView.backgroundColor = .blue
self.view.addSubview(progressView)
```

Call the following function to animate its width proportional to `progress`

```
func setProgress(_ progress: CGFloat) {
    let fullWidth: CGFloat = 200
    let newWidth = progress/100*fullWidth
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) {
        self.progressView.frame.size = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: self.progressView.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Create a `progressLabel` and a `currentProgress` variable

```
let progressLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
var currentProgress: CGFloat = 0
label.text = String(currentProgress)
self.view.addSubview(progressLabel)
```

Call the following function to update its progress in a loop with delay, example: `setLabelProgress(initialValue: self.currentProgress, targetValue: 70)`

```
func setLabelProgress(initialValue: CGFloat, targetValue: CGFloat) {

    guard currentProgress != targetValue else { return }

    let range = targetValue - initialValue
    let increment = range/CGFloat(abs(range))
    let duration: TimeInterval = 1.5
    let delay = duration/TimeInterval(range)
    currentProgress += increment
    progressLabel.text = String(describing: currentProgress)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay) {
        self.setLabelProgress(initialValue: initialValue, targetValue: targetValue)
    }
}
```

For the second label call the same function but swapping `initialValue` and `targetValue`